# A Covering Map $\mathbb{R}P^2\longrightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I came across the following problem:  Any covering map $\mathbb{R}P^2\longrightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism.  To solve the problem you can look at the composition of covering maps 
$$
S^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2\longrightarrow X
$$
and examine the deck transformations to show that the covering $S^2\longrightarrow X$ only has the identity and antipodal maps as deck transformations.

I've seen these types of problems solved by showing that the covering is one-sheeted.  Is there a solution to the problem along those lines?

EDIT:  Even if there isn't a way to do it by showing it is one-sheeted, are there other ways?

Comment: What other examples od "these types of problems" which are solved by doing that have you seen?

Comment: Show that $X$ is manifold like $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and then use fact that $\pi_1(X)$ have subgroup isomorphic with $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and classification of surfaces (like Ted proposed).

Comment: related: [Why isn't $\mathbb{CP}^2$ a covering space for any other manifold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24784/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using Euler characteristic? Euler characteristic is multiplicative for a covering map: If $E\to B$ is an $n$-sheeted covering space and $E$ is compact, then $\chi(E)=n\chi(B)$. Since $\chi(\mathbb RP^2)=1$, we're done.

Comment: Why is it that the fibre having cardinality $1$ implies that $f$ is a homeomorphism? Is $f$ assumed to be surjective (Hatcher does not)?

Comment: So far as I am concerned, covering maps are surjective. I don't remember Hatcher's rationale for being non-standard.

Comment: Thanks Ted. So your solution has shown that any such $f$ is bijective we already know $f$ is a local homeomorphism so $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Perhaps you should point out that by compactness it can't be an infinite-sheeted cover either.

Comment: The surjectivity is a consequence of the definition: each point of the covered space has an evenly covered neighborhood.

Comment: @Lano: Of course, but Hatcher — for reasons I can't distill — explicitly comments that the preimage of that neighborhood may be allowed to be empty. When the base space is connected, we all agree.

Comment: Doesn't that comment seem a bit incoherent?Mmm..actually if $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover, by that definition $p$ should be onto..

Answer (score 3):

1-Prove that $X$ has to be a compact topological surface;

2-Prove that such a covering has to be finite-sheeted;

3-Deduce from 2 and from $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ that $\pi_1(X)$ is finite;

4- Since the map induced by the covering projection on $\pi_1$ is injective you get $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}< \pi_1(X)$;

5-Conclude using the classification of compact topological surfaces.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. (+1)